# PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX creates unreliable PrivateUsage field, why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory, memory-leaks

Using the following code on VS 2012, native C++ development:

```
SIZE_T CppUnitTests_MemoryValidation::TakeMemoryUsageSnapshot() {  
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX processMemoryCounter;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*)
        &processMemoryCounter, sizeof(processMemoryCounter));
    return processMemoryCounter.PrivateUsage;
}
```

I call this method before and after each `CPPUnitTest` and calculate the difference of the `PrivateUsage` field. Normally this difference should be zero, assuming my memory allocation doesn't leak.

Only simple things happen inside my test class. Even without any memory allocation, just creating an instance of my test class and releasing it again, sometimes (not in every test iteration) the difference gets above zero, so this scheme seems to be non-deterministic.

Is there somebody with more insight than me who could either explain how to tackle this or tell me what is wrong with my assumptions?

Comment: PrivateUsage includes the heap blocks that were released and are now in the free block list, ready to be re-used.  Use the [debug allocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In short, your assumptions are not correct. There can be a lot of other things going on in your process that perform memory allocation ([the Event Tracing thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/12/10498659.aspx), and any others created by third-party add-ons on your system) so it is not surprising to see memory use go up occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Following Hans Passants debug allocator link, I noticed some more information about memory leak detection instrumentation by Microsoft, in special the _CrtMemCheckpoint function(s).

The link i followed was "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tz9b54s(v=vs.90).aspx"

Now when taking my memory snapshots with this function and checking for a difference using the _CrtMemDifference function, this seems to work reliable and deterministic.